# PHP POST via JSON is empty

Tags: php, json

I have a basic form that post to PHP file.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input name="operation" id="operation" placeholder="operation" />
<br>
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
<br>
<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<br>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<br>
<button type="submit" >POST</button>
</form>
```

problem is the operation is posting NULL or empty via the index file below.
I am using the basic php://input to get encoded via json.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    if(isset($data -> operation)){

      $operation = $data -> operation;
      echo $operation;
       if(!empty($operation)){

       }else{

           //$operation is empty ...

       }

     }else{

          //$operation is not set ...

     }

  }
```

However echoing the file_get_contents('php://input') displays the correct values from the posted form.

Any reason why the $operation return is always empty?

Comment: its a text field and is used like so ... if($operation == 'register'){ //...}

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($data->operation, $operation);` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: both var_dump($data->operation); //returns NULL  var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))); //returns NULL yet i physically type a value into the form input ...

Comment: more debugging: `var_dump($_POST, $_POST['operation']);` to see if it is in there?

Comment: Yes both var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); var_dump($_POST, $_POST['operation']); output the POST Data ...

Comment: So, the 'operation' entry  is in `$_POST`, and has the expected value, but not in `$data`. Maybe the `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` doesn't always do what is expected? If you want it as an object then you could do: `$data = (object) $_POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should be prepared before convert to Json format Try this code :)
I test this Code, it work.
Good Luck

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = str_replace('=','":"',$data);
    $data = str_replace('&','","',$data);
    $data = '{"'.$data.'"}';

    $data = json_decode($data);

    if(isset($data->operation)){

      $operation = $data -> operation;
      echo $operation;
       if(!empty($operation)){
            echo "NOT EMPTY";
       }else{

            echo "IS EMPTY";
           //$operation is empty ...

       }

     }else{
            echo "NO OPERATION";
          //$operation is not set ...

     }

  }
```